# Python - Server / Client TCP Chat Console

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, console-application, chat

I'm trying to make a Host/ClientTCP Chat Console.

I have a little problem with my python script, actually, i can't assign my listenS socket when i'm in server mode.

I want to use the same functions (Send and Recieve) for the Client and Host but i don't know if it is possible, i'm not very good in python so if you guys can help me to solve this

Thanks

Code :

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Port = 1604

listenS = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def start():
    IP_address = "192.168.1.49"
    isserver = input("Server ? (Y/N) : ")
    if isserver.lower() == "n":
        rIP = input("IP Adress : ")
          # str(rIP)
    rPort = input("Port : ")
    if rPort != "":
        Port = int(rPort)
    else:
        Port = 1604
    if isserver.lower() == "n":
        listenS.connect((IP_address, Port))
    elif isserver.lower() == "y":
        Listen()

def Listen():
    try:
        server.bind(('', Port))
        server.listen(10)
        listenS, addr = server.accept() # ---- Here is my problem ! -----
    except:
        print("Connection Timed Out !")

class Send(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        print("Sender Started...")

    def run(self):
        while True:
            message = input() + "\n"
            listenS.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

class Recieve(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        print("Listener Started...")

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print(listenS)
            message = listenS.recv(2048)
            print(str(message).replace(r"\n","").replace(r"b'","").replace(r"'",""))

start()
send = Send()
recieve = Recieve()

send.start()
recieve.start()
```

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your example.  Please work to provide a [mcve] along with expected and actual results and the full traceback of any error messages ("here is my problem" doesn't describe the problem).  Some issues:  `Port` is both a global and local variable (local in `start`, but global in `Listen`).  `rIP` is never used.  `listenS` is both global and local as well.

Comment: first problem are local and global variables - you ask for port and assing to local variable and later `Listen` use global 1604. Better send values as arguments - ie. `Listen(Port)` and maybe use `return`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, i'm sorry if i didn't detailed enough my problem , i fixed all the issues concerning the local and global variables, so now it works =)